# How to determine if a SQL statement will run?

Tags: mysql

Tell me whether the query is correct or contains any error:

```
select cname from company where id IN (
    select company_id,count(*) from medication
    group by(company_id) having count(*)>1
)
order by cname;
```

Comment: Did it run? Did you get any errors?

Comment: depends on the table structure and the expected result the query shall yield

Answer (score 0):

Contains an error you cannot have **in (select company_id, count(*)***
removing the count() might work for you please check below

```
/*
create table company(id int,cname varchar(10));
insert into company values
(1,'abc'),(2,'def'),(3,'ghi');

create table medication(id int,company_id int);
truncate table medication;
insert into medication values
(1,1),
(2,1),
(3,1),
(4,2),
(5,2),
(6,2),
(7,3),
(8,2);
*/
```

this code

```
select cname from company 
where id IN (select company_id from medication group by(company_id) having count(*) > 1) 
order by cname;
```

results in

```
+-------+
| cname |
+-------+
| abc   |
| def   |
+-------+
```

Answer (score -1):

For your reference. You can always run your query on MySQl/PHPMyadmin so they will show which error you have.

Alternatively you can use below tools

https://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/

http://sqlfiddle.com/

I hope it helps